# Any better way to locate whitespaces on binary images?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

[image][image]

This is a picture of a corridor after masking.

I'm trying to follow the "free path" in an indoor environment using opencv, the way I'm trying to locate the free area or whitespace in the image is by traversing the whole array and checking the pixel values, but this seems too slow. I also tried using findContours and edge detection methods from opencv but the largest contour area is pointing at the far left corner of the white area. Any other way I can do this ?

Comment: Did you display contour ? (not the bounding box) if you do so  it's easy to get the area using area = cv.contourArea(largestCountour) (you can also count white pixels using cv::countNonZero )

Comment: Yeah the contours looked fine, can you tell me how to locate the detected area, like left, right or center of the image ?

Comment: Check this opencv tutorial ; (section 7 : Bounding Box) https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: Thanks. I followed the same previously and it gave me a really small bounding rectangle on far left.

Comment: Can you include that image result in your question ?

Comment: Added, the bounding rectangle is red colored dot, also, I drawed the rectangle on the largest contour.

Comment: What do you mean "locate whitespaces"? Can mean their center of mass, set of connected components, or many other things.

Comment: center point, or which region has the most white pixels. I basically want to know in which part of the image the white area is.

Comment: I see only 1 red dot where is the bounding rectangle ?                                        x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

Comment: @Syed Center of mass of white pixels will likely work. Write a for loop. If it's too slow, use a faster language than Python. In C# or C++, the fast way is reading blocks 16/32 bytes (SSE2/AVX2 register size), compare them with all 0 and all 1, and only process individual pixels in the register when it's a combination of black and white pixels.

Comment: The code is straightforward, iterate over pixels, accumulate 3 64-bit counters: total white count, total white X, total white Y. After you've read the complete image, divide total XY by count and you'll get center of mass XY.

Comment: Or, just use [`connectedComponentsWithStats`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f) which will return the centroid of each component.

Comment: @Ziri I used the same functions you mentioned to draw the rectangle, it outputs a small dot/rectangle.

Comment: Assuming your binary image is called `thresh`, use `np.where(thresh > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('YourImagePAth\\image.png')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
idx =0
for cnt in contours:
    idx += 1
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi=im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    cv2.drawContours(im,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow('img',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

now if you want the white pixels area use : area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
and if you want the red rectangle area use : w*h (bounding box dimensions).

This is what you should get if you draw the bounding box using the code above :

[image]